# Is the definition of these variables necessary?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

## I didn't write this code it was provided as part of coursework.

I am completing the Flatiron Prep work and found this interesting.

```
first_name = ""
last_name = ""
for key, value in example_dictionary.items():
    if key == "last_name":
        last_name = value.title()
    if key == "first_name":
        first_name = value
print(first_name, last_name)
```

I then decided to try this without the intial  
`first_name = ""
last_name = ""`

such that

```
for key, value in example_dictionary.items():
    if key == "last_name":
        last_name = value.title()
    if key == "first_name":
        first_name = value
print(first_name, last_name)
```

and it still seems to work. Can I get an explanation for why they defined `first_name` and `last_name` as such if it is seemingly unnecessary?

Comment: What happens if your dictionary is missing the `first_name` key?

Comment: Did you mean to say **without the initial**?

Comment: @Barmar that is a good question, but the reason we are using this key is because it is part of the dictionary.

Comment: But the reason they initialize the variables is so they don't get an error if there's a missing key.

Comment: @Barmar no I am just stating that they are defining these two variables in the beginning, as in initially

Comment: @Barmar I see. So it really is just for good practice then.

Comment: This makes no sense "I then decided to try this out the intial". I think you meant "without" in there.

Comment: Side note, you seem to be unaware of the fact that you can *index* a dict directly. `example_dictionary['first_name']` will directly retrieve the value associated with `'first_name'`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica No haha I am not unaware I am just asking a question as to why the writers of this course decided to define the variables as empty quotes before formally starting the for loop.

Comment: because they don't want to pop up error in the print statement if the dictionary that looping through don't have key with `last_name` and `first_name` then the variables in the print() statement won't be defined. But Barmar have better way of writing this in his answer

Comment: @Dave: Considering that the writers didn't just index the dict, there's not much point in speculating why they did other things that don't make sense. Sure, it *could* be for if the keys don't exist, but it could also just be dumb and pointless.

Answer (score 3):

The initial values are defaults to use if the dictionary doesn't have the corresponding keys. It's a very common programming mistake to assign a variable conditionally, and forget to handle the situation where the condition never occurs. Initializing the variables at the beginning avoids this mistake.

Another way to write this would be without the loop.

```
first_name = example_dictionary.get("first_name", "")
last_name = example_dictionary.get("last_name", "")
```

The second argument to `.get()` is a default value to return if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context, we cannot know for sure. But in general, if those variables are not initialized before the loop, and also nothing in the loop initializes them, then they will possibly not exist after the loop, and when you attempt to use them an exception will be raised. Better to have them initialized to impossible known states before the loop, so that the following code can be better able to interpret the values it finds in them.

Or if they are initialized before this, they may contain leftovers from previous operations which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

"Necessary" is maybe ill-defined here, but if we are talking in a strict sense, no it is not necessary, as stated, the program "still seems to work" without the initial lines.

What may be more useful is to ask what are the consequences of removing these lines.

The final statement of your code snips here `print(first_name, last_name)` tries to evaluate the names, i.e. identifiers, `first_name` and `last_name`.  Python will attempt to resolve these names within first the local, then global variable scope.  If a name is not able to be resolved, the execution of the statement will stop, and a [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) will be raised.  A name error is just an exception, and can be [handled](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the normal way (though catching `NameError`s is a bit unusual).

So the consequence of removing these initial variable assignments from your code are that

1. `first_name` and `last_name` no longer have a "default value", though [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674846/11424673) gives an alternative method to retain this.
2. In the case that `first_name` and `last_name` are not found as keys in `example_dictionary`, instead of gracefully continuing with default values, your code will raise a `NameError`.  This may actually be preferrable in some cases, after all, **[exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)** are meant to tell us when something **exceptional** has happened.  Let's suppose that your code really needs to assign a meaningful `last_name` and `first_name` before continuing. It may be best to raise an exception and halt execution here instead of continuing with meaningless data.